# PHP: strange behavior of foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Below the code which *works as expected before I try to use* `key` while iteration.
As I do it, I see an error: "Allowed memory size of 1073741824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 9223372043239833600 bytes)". See at the required memory size, it looks monstrous.

The `getModules` returns an associative array, `$id` is a `string`.

Any idea about possible reasons?

```php
             foreach (Yii::$app->getModules() as $id => $module) {
                    echo '<pre>';
                    var_dump(gettype($module));
                    if (gettype($module) =='array') {
                        var_dump($module);
                    } else if (gettype($module) =='object') {
                        var_dump(get_class($module));
                    }
                    //var_dump($id); // <-- We have problems when try to uncomment this
                    echo '</pre>';
             }
```

`php -v`:

```
PHP 7.0.33-25+0~20200225.32+debian9~1.gbpa11893 (cli) (built: Feb 25 2020 13:16:41) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.33-25+0~20200225.32+debian9~1.gbpa11893, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

UPDATED:
I just opened and saved the modules array via ssh and the bug disappears. I have no guess what it was. Looks like an SSD glitch.

Comment: how many modules you have ?

Comment: 30. In this array one item is an instance of lightweight module, others are associative arrays, most of them have only one item.

Comment: Yii::$app->getModules() keep it in some variable and then run loop for that variable, and show the result of Yii::$app->getModules().

Comment: Can't do it. Got same error while trying to dump the array in a file. Seems the key is not to blame? I must search a reason the in module instance.

Comment: Do you have the same issue with only row with a var_dump($module) in the foreach-loop?

Comment: No. Additionaly, I remove the module object from the array but still have the issue with access to $id or with var_dump out of loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an `opcache` problem. I edited and saved some files but the bug appeared here and there on site pages. So I got that the reason is the cache and just executed `opcache_reset()`.

Hope this solution will be useful for somebody else.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you allways reload all your module each times ou execute the foreach.

Add a variable before to store your modules list, and that's ok.

The corrected code :

```
$listOfModules = Yii::$app->getModules();
     foreach ( $listOfModules  as $id => $module) {
                    echo '<pre>';
                    var_dump(gettype($module));
                    if (gettype($module) =='array') {
                        var_dump($module);
                    } else if (gettype($module) =='object') {
                        var_dump(get_class($module));
                    }
                    //var_dump($id); // <-- We have problems when try to uncomment this
                    echo '</pre>';
             }
```

Comment: Yes, I got it and have this code changed already but this editing has no effect. I still have the code crashed when I use $id.

Comment: you sure id was string ? and not something more big ?

Comment: It must contains only items from config file. I can't imagine how something big can be added to